# Plot the numerical solution of the differential equation for 0 ≤ t ≤ 50: x''[t] + 0.15x'[t] − x[t] + x[t]^3 == 0.3 Cos[t], x[0] == −1 , x'[0] == 1

Tags: differential-equations

What am I doing wrong here ???

***[image: In[195]:= DSolve[{x''[t] + 0.15 x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 == 0.3 Cos[t], x[0] == -1,x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t] Out[195]= DSolve[{-x[t] + x[t]^3 + 0.15 Derivative[1][x][t] + (x^[Prime][Prime])[t] == 0.3 Cos[t],x[0] == -1, Derivative[1][x][0] == 0}, x[t], t]]***

Comment: Use `NDSolve` for a **numeric** solution

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The short answer is that `DSolve` does not know how to solve it. To plot the solution: `ListLinePlot[NDSolve[..., x, {t, 0, 50}]` where you put your list of ODE equations in for the `...`

Comment: That's the Duffing equation. It doesn't have a closed-form solution (it allows for chaotic behavior). Like @BobHanlon said, use `NDSolve` for a numeric one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it arises from a lack of understanding of the mathematics of the problem at hand.

Comment: I do not see any evidence this user has a lack of understanding of the math:  he simply asked for help plotting a numeric solution to a DE and was obviously unfamiliar with both this forum and the precise way to do this in Mathematica.  Really should have cut him a break as a new user rather than insult him and close his thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an array of the DE and initial conditions to pass to NDSolve along with the solution variables and integration range.  NDSolve will then return rules like x->mySol and so forth.  Need to de-reference these with x[t]/.theSol.  Then pass it to Plot.  The ClearAll command just clears everything for this  example in case you cut and past this code into a notebook that has already defined x like x=3 which would cause NDSolve to fail.  Keep in mind this command clears ALL user defined variables so omit it if you wish.

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
mySol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 0.15 x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 == 0.3 Cos[t], 
   x[0] == -1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 50}]
Plot[x[t] /. mySol, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]